# Camel idempotentConsumer always use PUT instead of GET

Tags: apache-camel

I am using camel idempotent. Can someone please explain the logic behind idempotentConsumer xml tag.

I received file for first time. All good the idempotentconsumer block executed. on infinispan server I see a log PUT.

I dropped a duplicate file. Now idempotentconsumer identifies duplicated but on infinispan server I see a log **with PUT instead of GET**. I am wondering is this issue with server side or camel-client?

```
<idempotentConsumer messageIdRepositoryRef="infinispanRepo" >
<header>CamelFileAbsolutePath</header>
</idempotentConsumer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is working as designed. The Idempotent Consumer EIP will attempt to put the key to the cache with a fixed value of `true` - that would be an atomic operation on Infinispan. The result of that put operation is then used to know if there was a duplicate or not.

If you do two operations with a GET and then PUT its no longer an atomic operation and you can end up with problems.

See the code at: 
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-infinispan/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/infinispan/processor/idempotent/InfinispanIdempotentRepository.java#L68

Comment: Thanks for the INFO. I have gone through because of PUT the lifespan changes incase of duplicate. Example: Cache timeout is 10min. I received a duplicate file I assume the file get processed after 10min but when ever the polling checks for duplicate the lifespan keeps on updating and the cache never expires and the file just sits throwing duplicate.

Comment: Ah thanks for the comment, we can likely improve this to do a GET first and then a PUT if empty: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12327

Comment: Awesome... Thanks heap